# How do I access a specific property from a local storage object? (Angular 2/angular-2-local-storage)

Tags: javascript, angular

So I'm storing an object into local storage using [angular-2-local-storage](https://github.com/phenomnomnominal/angular-2-local-storage) as such:

`this.localStorage.set('myObject', {'prop1': "string", 'prop2': "string"});`

Then I'm trying to get a specific property of that object as such:

`this.localStorage.get('myObject').prop1;`

But doing this gives me the error `Property 'prop1' does not exist on type '{}'`

I've also tried storing the object in a local variable, and then trying to access the property as such, but it gives me the same error.

`var myObject = this.localStorage.get('myObject');
var myProperty = myObject.prop1;`

What am I doing wrong, and how do I access the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using localStorage.setItem / localStorage.getItem with Angular2, so it's maybe not the same behavior. But have you tried by stringifying and parsing your object ?

In my case :

```
localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify({'prop1': "string", 'prop2': "string"}));
let temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject'));
temp.prop1; // gives "string"
```

In your case, something like :

```
localStorage.set('myObject', JSON.stringify({'prop1': "string", 'prop2': "string"}));
let temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.get('myObject'));
temp.prop1;
```

Hope it cans help !

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work and gives me the same error.

Comment: Damned, if you write "localStorage" in your Chrome console, what does it look ?

Comment: Storage {
  my-app.myObject: "{"prop1": "string", "prop2": "string"}"
}

Comment: When I simply do `localStorage.get('myObject')` it returns the object already as a JSON object, so I don't know why it won't let me get its property as `localStorage.get('myObject').prop1`

Comment: Is localStorage.get('myObject')['prop1'] working ? Can you give me the result of localStorage.get('myObject') please ?

Comment: THANK YOU. `localStorage.get('myObject')['prop1']` worked. Question, if you know the answer. Why would doing that work but not `localStorage.get('myObject').prop1`?

Comment: Great if it works !! I'm not really sure but I have similar problems since I work with ES6 and Typescript, the Object type is more strong.

Answer (score 3):

You must save the object as a string

```
localStorage.setItem('myObjectName', JSON.stringify(this.myObject));
```

and then obtain the string and convert it to an object

```
  this.myObject =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObjectName'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work and gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details about how you are configuring you angular2 local storage. I checked the source code and its doing the parsing and stringifing before you get or set respectively.I have not tested it but you should be able to do the following:

```
 import { LocalStorageModule } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LocalStorageModule.withConfig({
            prefix: 'my-app',
            storageType: 'localStorage'
        })
    ],
    declarations: [
        ..
    ],
    providers: [
        ..
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and then in you component you can inject this service as following

```
constructor (
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) {

    }
ngOnInit() {
    this.localStorageService.set(key, value);
    console.log(this.localStorageService.get(key));
}
```

You dont have to parse or stringify anything. Hope this will help.
AGAIN: I have not tested it this code is entirely based on angular-2-local-storage documentation.

Comment: That is exactly how I am configuring local storage. Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: Here is the working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/k3T769bOipJ08cyo34M6?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Strangely, it doesn't work for me, even though its working in that Plunkr. And its configured exactly the same way. Doing `this.localStorageService.get('myObject')['prop1']` does work though.

Comment: @JunKang can you accept the answer  if it satisfies your question i can move my plnkr to my original answer then and if you can share your code in plnkr i can take a look at it for you. thanks.